# How to serve a file with correct filename and extension in Koa?

Tags: koa

I am trying to let a user upload a file with Koa framework, store it on the server side and allow it to download again later.

When uploading a file with koa-body, the file gets uploaded without extension and a random string, how do serve the file as download with original filename and extension?

All examples online I have found online assume that the file got uploaded with the original filename, which is not the case here.

```
const bodyparser = require('koa-body');

app.use(bodyparser({
  formidable: { uploadDir: './uploads' },
  multipart: true,
  basedir: './views',
  apps: app,
}));
```

The files get uploaded correctly into the upload folder, but the filename and extension are stripped and replaced by a random string. (ex. upload_1d421fb33fcd1d43efc41352975358da)

```
router.post('/add', add);
router.get('/download/:filename', getDownload);

async function add(ctx) {
  const { body } = ctx.request;
  const thingfile = await ctx.request.files.thingfile;
  things.push({ name: body.thing, file: thingfile });

  ctx.redirect('/');
}

async function getDownload(ctx) {
  const {filename} = ctx.params;
  ctx.attachment(filename);
  await send(ctx, fname, { root: __dirname + '/uploads' });
}
```

I can download the file when calling URL/uploads/upload_1d421fb33fcd1d43efc41352975358da , but the file would have to be manually renamed on the client side to work properly.

Obviously I'm missing something or I am doing it completely wrong.
I'm a bit lost here so thank you in advance to guide me back on track!

Answer (score 0):

I am uesing the koa-body and could get actually name

```js
router.post('/stream', async (ctx) => {
  const { file } = ctx.request.files
  const { path, name } = file
  ctx.body = name
})
```

You can add the name attribute to the middleware configuration.

```
app.use(bodyparser({
  multipart: true,
  formidable: {

    keepExtensions: true,
    onFileBegin: (name, file) => {

      console.log(name)
      // get the file extension
      const ext = name.split('.').pop()
      console.log(ext)

    },
  },
}))
```

you can console.log the name